# What latitude/longitude format is this?

Tags: php, google-maps, geolocation, gps

I need to convert the following to decimal coordinates for consumption by a Google map.  These are artficial reefs off the coast of Florida USA.  When I use the following tool for example: http://www.earthpoint.us/BatchConvert.aspx  The resulting coordinates that are output are somewhere in China.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Description Longitude   Latitude
3 WALTER LIMESTONE UNITS, 1 ECOSYSTEM REEF ON BASE & 1 GROUPER UNITS    85 41.758   29 47.187
1 WALTER LIMESTONE UNITS, 1 ECOSYSTEM REEF ON BASE & 3 GROUPER UNITS    85 32.558   29 55.222
4 WALTER LIMESTONE UNITS AND 1 ECOSYSTEM REEF ON BASE   85 32.577   29 55.063
5 WALTER LIMESTONE UNITS AND 1 ECOSYSTEM REEF ON BASE   85 32.638   29 54.549
5 WALTER LIMESTONE UNITS AND 3 ECOSYSTEM REEF ON BASE   85 32.69    29 54.25
2 WALTER LIMESTONE UNITS AND 1 ECOSYSTEM REEF ON BASE   85 32.362   29 55.253
47 FT LONG X 14 FT WIDE X 10 FT TALL FERRO-CEMENT SAILBOAT-FUNDED BY MBARA  85 32.405   29 54.385
2 WALTER LIMESTONE UNITS    85 32.362   29 55.253
8 WALTER LIMESTONE UNITS,2 ECOSYSTEM REEF ON BASE & 3 GROUPER UNITS 85 32.542   29 55.438
8 WALTER LIMESTONE UNITS AND 1 ECOSYSTEM REEF ON BASE   85 32.36    29 54.567
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the minus is missing in your coordinates in longitude column.
And this format is DD MM.MMM (decimal degrees, minutes). So this

```
3 WALTER LIMESTONE UNITS, 1 ECOSYSTEM REEF ON BASE & 1 GROUPER UNITS    85 41.758   29 47.187
```

is converted to

```
29.78645 (lat); -84.30403 (lon)
```

That's nearby Florida. You may use this converter:
http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/convert_lat_long/

Comment: OMG, that is too funny!  The state of Florida is misreporting their coordinates...thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Florida is around Latitude: 27.787899, Longitude: -81.578979

Your data is stored badly. In the first row:

```
3 WALTER LIMESTONE UNITS, 1 ECOSYSTEM REEF ON BASE & 1 GROUPER UNITS    85 41.758   29 47.187
```

you need to flip the sign of the first value, but also to query them as:
    `29.47187, -85.41758`

This will display as [this](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=29.47187,+-85.41758&hl=en&sll=29.477861,-85.407715&sspn=0.419624,0.728531&t=h&z=5) on google maps.

Comment: It seems the source coordinates have the minute part in 60" units, not in decimals. It's betrayed by format (space) and up limit of integer part (<=60 in listed points).